# Extending bundles from the outside in Symfony / Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, bundle, symfony, extend

As far as I know, if you want to extend a bundle from another bundle, without creating a dependency between them or using any OO concept of inheritance, it is not yet possible w/ Symfony & Doctrine2. This confirmed my first idea :

"Due to the way Doctrine works, it is not possible to override entity mapping of a bundle." (source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping)

The only existing way did not give me satisfaction : using SuperMappedClasses...

What I want is, for instance:

1. having Contacts in a standalone bundle in one hand (CRMBundle)
2. having EmailMessages in an other standalone bundle in the other (EmailBundle)
3. adding "magically" the Contact::$emailMessages property + getter/setter + twig template in the ShowMapper (if I'm using Sonata, which is not mandatory) + fields in the DatagridMapper/FormMapper... when the EmailBundle is present in the App at the same time than the Contact/CRMBundle.
4. the same thing on the reverse side (Email)

For the moment, as the official Symfony doc says, it does not seem possible.
Anyone can confirm the "state of the art" on this point ?

In fact we are working on this here, and I think we are about to touch something new and interesting for everyone on that point... but I don't want us to work on this issue without the necessity for.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to create some "dynamic" property. There is no way to do this. 
IMO, either EmailMessages and Contact are separated entities, then they are in 2 different bundles and does not know each other (you can still use the e-mail address as a key to query from one to another), either they do and are part of the same "aggregate".

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm pretty sure that we can find a way to do what seems to be impossible. We'll work on it, do something, and then if we are successful, write something for the community and (if possible) publish some code.

Comment: IMO the issue is not technical - of course there are ways - but about modelisation. Either you have a model or another one, but having something dynamic/magic does not sound good.

Comment: And why doesn't it sound good ?
It's so useful to get an access to an entity's definition from outside its bundle to extend it on the fly...
It will provide an "Easy Extend Pattern", allowing to design stuff extendable, generic, and at the same time standalone.

Comment: I've just opened an issue in the Doctrine's Github repository : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6049